# C: Find member of the sequence by given criteria

Tags: c, math

I need help with the following C program:

For input value `EPS` which represents precision (`double` value), print first member of sequence so that the statement

```
abs(a(n)-a(n-1))<EPS
```

is true.

Sequence `a(n)` is given by:

```
a(n)=(1-1/2!)(1+1/3!)...(1+(-1)^n/(n+1)!)
```

I used this equation: `a(n)-a(n-1)=((-1)^n*(n+2))/(n+1)!`

My code doesn't give me any output:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int fact(int n)//function to find factorial of 'n'
{
 int i,f=1;
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        f=f*i;
 return f;
}

int main()
{
    double an=0.5,ap=2,EPS;//an is a_new, ap is a_previous
    int n=1;
    printf("EPS=");
    scanf("%lf",&EPS);
    do
    {
     int f=fact(n+1);
     n=n+1;
     an=ap+((double)(pow(-1.0,n)*(n+2)))/f;
    }
    while(fabs(an-ap)>EPS);
    printf("%lf",an);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Did you do some step by step debugging?

Comment: Maybe I´m too tired, but the formula looks wrong. How about `a(n+1) - a(n) = a(n) * (-1)^(n+1) / (n+2)!` ? (same as `a(n) - a(n-1) = a(n-1) * (-1)^n / (n+1)!`)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code at least,

1.`ap` not initialized

2. you should update `f` with new `n`, but now f = 2 for ever
3. also on the `while` loop, `an-as` should be `an-ap'